# Objects are not valid as a React child. If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

i want to render an email of all the users for testing purpose, In fact i have done that using this method. --- {dataFromApi.map((item, i) => {item.email}

)}  but still it didn't work

```
const [dataFromApi, setDataFromApi] = useState([]);

const URL = 'http://localhost:5000/users'
  const requestOptions = {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: { 
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
  }   
  const submit = () => {
    const data = fetch(URL, requestOptions);
    data.then( (userdata) => {
      return userdata.json();
    }).then( (data) => {
      setDataFromApi(data[0]);
      
    }).catch( (err) => {
      console.log(err);
    })
  }


  return (
      <div className="login">
      <h1 className="loginTitle">Choose a Login Method</h1>
      <p>{dataFromApi}</p>
      <div className="wrapper">
.
.
.
.
.
```

here is the API response

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "email": "test1234@gm.com",
    "password": null
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "email": null,
    "password": null
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "email": "test@123.com",
    "password": "12345678"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "email": "test@231.com",
    "password": "12345678"
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "email": "test@231.com",
    "password": "12345678"
  },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "email": "test@231.com",
    "password": "12345678"
  },
  {
    "id": 7,
    "email": "NEWtest@231.com",
    "password": "123"
  }
]
```

but getting this error

react_devtools_backend.js:4012 The above error occurred in the

component:

and

react-dom.development.js:14887 Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {id, email, password}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Comment: what is your expected output ?

Comment: You're trying to put a JS object into a paragraph tag. It's not going to work. You can use e.g. {dataFromApi.email} if you want to display the email address.

Comment: The API data is an array of objects, you're trying to render data[0] which is an object, and the error tells you that you can't do that. What's your question?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i want to render an email of all the users for testing purpose, In fact i have done that using this method     {dataFromApi.map((item, i) => <p key={i}>{item.email}</p>)}   but still it didn't work

Comment: {dataFromApi.email}   this is working but using map method is not working.... thank you @AdamPearson , thank you everyone

Answer (score 0):

Like Adam said in the comments, you are trying to pack a collection of things into a tag meant for a single thing. You should iterate over the list rendering a thing for each item.

```js
{dataFromApi.map((item, i) => <p key={i}>{item.email}</p>)}
```

Comment: i have done that too... but didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer why i'm not getting the expected output because in this code

```
const submit = () => {
const data = fetch(URL, requestOptions);
data.then( (userdata) => {
  return userdata.json();
}).then( (data) => {
  setDataFromApi(data[0]); // this will store only one object into an array
  
}).catch( (err) => {
  console.log(err);
})
```

}

here setDataFromApi(data[0]) will store only 1 object and to access the email from the object, we have to use only dataFromApi.email else dataFromApi will give only object which we can't render so that's why it is giving an error.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).